# how to integrate ccavenue payment gateway with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ccavenue

i'm new in integration of payment gateway.i don't know how to integrate that gateway.i want detailed steps..please help me.still now i didn't integrate so anyone help me.i have no idea for that integration.i have created one form contain one payment..whenever i clicking payment button it will go to ccavenue payment form.

```
<html>
<head><title>Payment</title></head>
<body>
<form action="" name="payment" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Payment">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: better u can contact ccavenue service provider .they can give enough information to integrate with ur web.